# Static function variable initialization order in the same function

Tags: c++

Consider the following.

```
void f() {
    static A a;
    static B b;
}
void g() {
    static C c;
    static D d;
}

void client() {
    f();
    g();
}
```

I know we can put the *global static* variable into *function* as `static local variable`. The variable will be initialized only when we call the function.
This can solve the initialization order issue. The `a` and `b` will be initialized before `c` and `d` when call `f()` first then `g()`.

But is it same when local static variables are defined in the same function?
Is `a` guaranteed to be initialized before `b`?

Comment: "This can solve the initialization order issue" - it can also complicate it for threaded code in earlier versions of c++;  just a pitfall to look out for if you're not aware of it.  But short answer; yes (though I lack time to find the quote for an answer).

Comment: Note this has to be true, because you can also write things like `static B b = process(a);`

Comment: @aschepler what you can write - and what leads to undefined behavior are not related. ;)

Comment: @UKMonkey Okay, yes. You can *validly* write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) (emphasis mine):

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier `static` have static storage duration but are initialized **the first time control passes through their declaration** (unless their initialization is zero- or constant-initialization, which can be performed before the block is first entered). On all further calls, the declaration is skipped.

Since control flows top-to-bottom, the variables will indeed be initialized in declaration order.

Answer (score 2):

> But is it same when local static variables are defined in the same function? Is a guaranteed to be initialized before b?

Yes, it's guaranteed. The two are a pair of declaration statements, and the general rule is that statement are executed in sequence:

> [**[stmt.stmt]/1**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.stmt#1)
>
> Except as indicated, statements are executed in sequence.

And the relevant "except" part for declaration statements is summarized by the cppreference article in [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856242/817643), or if one is a fan of reading stadnardese, in [[stmt.dcl]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.dcl#4).